# jQuery index on each function

Tags: jquery, indexing

I am curious why I need this index

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".divToggle").each(function(index){
            var buttonId = $(this)[0].attributes["id"].value.toString();
            var idParts = buttonId.split('_');
            var uniquePart = idParts[0] + "_" + idParts[1] + "_" + "divContentPanel";             
            $(this).click(function() {
                 $("#" + uniquePart).toggle("slow");
            });            
        });
    });
```

Why do I need the "[0]" in "var buttonId = $(this)[0]…"  Without it, I get an attributes["id"] is null error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".divToggle").each(function(index, element){
    var buttonId = element.id,
        idParts = buttonId.split('_'),
        uniquePart = idParts[0] + "_" + idParts[1] + "_" + "divContentPanel";

    $(element).click(function() {
         $("#" + uniquePart).toggle("slow");
    });            
});
```

Comment: This is a really cool solution, it is actually what I ended up using in my code. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead

```
var buttonId = this.id;
```

or jQuery way

```
var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 2):

with $(this) you are still in the jquery model where the correct way to get id is .attr("id")

writing $(this)[0] drops you back into the DOM model where its as you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this)[0]
```

Is doing 2 things -

1. Getting you the first element in the matched set, as you're looping round a set of results  one by one the index is probably redundant in this case
2. Returning a 'normal' JavaScript DOM object rather than a jQuery wrapped object

Looking at your code I believe you could achieve the same result by doing this -

```
var buttonId = this.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically you don't need it with a little modification of your code. What happens with jQuery selectors is they are simply a bunch of element references in an array.  so instead of

```
<div id ="myelement"></div>
```

you get

```
[<div id ="myelement"></div>]
```

using `$(this)` puts `this` in an array and allows it to be used with jQuery functions. If you aren't using jQuery functions just use `this`.  So your code would become

```
var buttonId = this.attributes["id"].value.toString();
```